# What is wrong with my semi-advanced PostgreSQL query? (Related to calculating with times and time intervals.)

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp, intervals

**Goal:**

Have a column (which doesn't exist in the table) representing the number of seconds left until the next time a recurring event is to take place, which is determined by "last done" (timestamptz) combined with the "time span string" column, which is a string such as "7 days" or "25 minutes" or "2 weeks" (standard PG compatible interval strings).

**The query:**

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    now() - "last done" - "time span string"::interval AS "seconds left until next" 
FROM "recurring events" 
ORDER BY "seconds left until next" DESC NULLS LAST;
```

The "seconds left until next" column bizarrely gets values such as:

```
-1 days +00:32:04.389802
```

**Expected value example:**

```
123456
```

I don't understand why it's not calculating with the columns. It seems to be constructing a string of their values in an interpreted manner or something. I don't know how to describe it.

I've tried to ::integer the AS expression, but that just gives me the error:

```
ERROR: cannot cast type interval to integer
```

The question isn't so much about the correct "formula"/order of the actual expression as the fact that it doesn't turn the column (or cell, rather) into an integer (representing the number of seconds left for that event until the next time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `now() - "last done" - "time span string"::interval`

In Postgres' date arithmetics, substracting timestamps generates a data of type `interval`, which is what you are seeing in the result.

You can turn this to seconds with `extract()`:

```
extract(epoch from (now() - "last done" - "time span string"::interval))
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that you are subtracting already looks like a number of seconds.  So, just subtract the two date/times and then convert to seconds and subtract the time span:

```
extract(epoch from (now() - "last done")) - "time span string"
```

Comment: Sadly can't mark your answer as right as well! (Even though it is, because the other guy got first.)

Comment: @Tobyn . . . As the OP you should accept whichever answer you think best answers your question.  You can take timing into account, but that is your prerogative.  GMB's answer is fine (they usually are); I answered because I think this is a simpler answer to your question.  You don't have to agree.